# Get all latest entries in users news feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, feed

Does anyone know of a way to retrieve the users entire news feed? Querying `/me/home` does filter some stories from. Also, it seems to retrieve the top stories. Is there any way to retrieve the latest stories?

It doesn't matter whether it's through the Graph API or FQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*me/home is pulling posts in order of created date on my end*

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/135669679827333/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dhome.limit(20).fields(created_time%2Cupdated_time%2Cid)

try this as your query, you can mod fields to include any you need.

```
me?fields=home.limit(20).fields(created_time,updated_time,id)
```

if it is still out of order because of your cookie settings from the actual home feed, you can force it to reorder by passing the array in sort(); "php".

for sort() refer to: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: I see. It does seem to sort by `created_time`. I guess I got confused because it seems that it doesn't retrieve all posts and I can't seem to figure out why. For example, I have subscribed to some profiles and the response doesn't include posts from these profiles.

Comment: It seems that it is possible to exclude status updates from the Facebook developer platform through the privacy settings. That's probably why I'm not getting all entries.